# How to paint the hilltop house

Tags: painting, exterior

What equipment would you guys use to paint on a slope? The house is at the top of a hill (basement plus two stories) and there is no level place to paint from. It is quite high. My husband is afraid of heights, but I’m not. Is there a way to do it safely with a ladder? Is there a way to navigate the roof more safely since I will be painting from there at times?

Comment: How steep is the roof?

Comment: I honestly couldn’t tell you the slope of the roof. It is very steep. I’m a nurse and amateur diy homeowner, so none of this is my wheelhouse.

Comment: Steep roofs are **not** for amateur painters. Don't even try. Go with scaffolding.

Comment: A friend has a boom lift I've borrowed from time to time.  Now I can't go back :)

Answer (score 4):

A ladder can be difficult to manage on a slope.  I'd use some scaffolding.  You can get extensions to level the structure so that it can handle a slope.  It's relatively inexpensive to rent.  Talk to your local equipment rental dealer about some specific recommendations for your situation.

Comment: I'd even consider using engineered scaffold. (Instead of pre-sized sections, specialty installers come out and install everything to conform to your exact situation.) It might look more expensive than renting scaffolding, but you save in time and probably increase safety. And stay off a steep roof unless you know a lot about industrial rope safety.

Comment: AND have a watcher.  "One to fall, one to call".